# Datepicker jquery ui not working in part of main view

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have a problem with my datetime picker.

I have JavaScript code at `view.htm` that load `view_part.htm` as search result.

At `view_part.htm`, I create datetime picker using jQuery UI, but it didn't show up. I wrote the jQuery code at `view.htm` and it still doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
for(i=0;i<sum;i++){
    $("#TGL_APPROVE_"+i).datepicker();
    $("#TGL_APPROVE_"+i).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
}
```

This is my view:

> [image: http://i47.tinypic.com/xu452.jpg]

Comment: did you include all neccessery files? are Ids of input element right(#TGL_APPROVE_0,#TGL_APPROVE_1,#TGL_APPROVE_2 son on  )? What error do you have?

Comment: I surely did that. Because, actually i also have a datepicker field at view.htm, it work. but When my datepicker field at view.htm it didn't work. The error is just the datetime picker didn't showed up

Comment: Can you add code which loads the view_part into your view? It looks like you need to find a mechanism to bind datepicker on DOM restructuring, since you DOM gets manipulated every time.

Comment: please add part of your html code in your question and check if all javascript library are include in your view.htm. When did you add the datepicker to your #TGL_APPROVE_ elements ? onload ?

Comment: $("#cont_list").load('<?=HOME?><?=APPID?>/cont_list?no_req={$row_request.NO_REQUEST} #list', function(data) {           
}); this code load view_part.htm into <div id=cont_list> </div> in view.htm

Comment: @palmplam : yes onload, I already put it into $(function(){});

Comment: like @techfoobar say, it's seems you are loading datepicker before the view_part.htm content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your variables `i` & `sum` refer to here, but as per the code in your comments you need to do something like this:

```
$("#cont_list").load('<?=HOME?><?=APPID?>/cont_list?no_req={$row_request.NO_REQU‌​EST} #list', function(data) { 
    for(i=0;i<sum;i++){
        $("#TGL_APPROVE_"+i).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
    }
});
```

the callback here ensures that **datepicker** is bind to your element whenever they are added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like it is because you are binding the datepicker before the content from view_part.html actually gets into the DOM.

What you need to do is bind it *after* it is loaded (via AJAX) and inserted into the DOM.

---

**Update**

```
$("#cont_list").load('<?=HOME?><?=APPID?>/cont_list?no_req={$row_request.NO_REQU‌​‌​EST} #list', function(data) {

   // bind datepicker here. 
   // Ensure 'sum' has a value before doing so.
   for(var i=0;i<sum;i++){
      $("#TGL_APPROVE_"+i).datepicker();
      $("#TGL_APPROVE_"+i).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
   }
});
```

Even better, if you can give a class to all the elements you want to bind datepicker to, it'll be easier. For example, if you specify `class="attachdp"` to those elements, you replace the `for` loop with:

```
$(".attachdp').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Comment: If you can post your JS code that *loads* view_part.html, i can tell you where exactly to bind the datepicker in.

Comment: $("#cont_list").load('<?=HOME?><?=APPID?>/cont_list?no_req={$row_request.NO_REQU‌​EST} #list', function(data) { });

this code load view_part.htm into <div id="cont_list"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Firebug plugin for FireFox to see any javascript errors.

However to solve your problem, if you give those inputs a class. Let's say "hasDatePicker".

Then after you loaded the content via AJAX (Or are you using a iFrame?)

```
$(".hasDatePicker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to all filed that should support datapicker plugin. and you will be able do it in more simple way:

```
$(function() {
   $(".datapicker").datepicker();
 }
```

this is shortcut of document.ready(), so when whole page is loaded, there will binding datapickers

Comment: thanks, but i already put this code into that binding. and still didn't worked

Comment: If you add this part within AJAX you need this js in your part. And when your part inculed in html, all your datapicker will init

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling view_part.htm ? I'm assuming by AJAX?

If yes - you should call datepicker() either in the ajax callback or once view_part.htm has fully loaded.
eg in view_part:

```
<script>
$(function(){
for(i=0;i<sum;i++){
    $("#TGL_APPROVE_"+i).datepicker();
    $("#TGL_APPROVE_"+i).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
}
});
</script>
```